# Cleanup after all JUnit test runs

Tags: java, junit

In my project I have to do some repository setup before all tests and after successful tests I want to clean up, I know @afterClass is used for this but it requires static  variables but i dont want to make my objects statics, so is there any other way by which I can achieve this??

Comment: You can always use `@Before` and `@After` so your setup will be recreated on start of every test

Comment: @vinayknl I have already saw that answer , please read my question properly, i want to cleanup but dont want to define my objects static, i know about using beforeClass and afterClass

Comment: "dont want to define my objects static" Why?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using JUnit4, then use `@After`. Documentation [here](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/After.html). Note that your methods annotated this way will be executed after each test case, in a similar fashion to `@Before` being executed before each test case.

If you're writing an integration test with multiple test cases and your setup is heavy, you could use a combination of `@BeforeClass` to set up static objects and `@After` to mutate/clean up/reset certain parts of these objects' states. This, of course, would violate your requirement of not using static variables, but I can't really see the rationale behind that requirement. Recall that JUnit instantiates the test class once for every single test case.

Answer (score 2):

If you want set up and tear down before and after each test method, use `@Before` and `@After`. If you want to set up once, run all your tests and then tear down, use `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass`.

Yes, `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` are static methods, but note that JUnit recreates your test class instance for each test method, so you cannot maintain any information in non-static fields of a test class across different tests.

I, as the other commenters here, have a feeling that you want to avoid static fields because there's a common opinion that they are bad practice. Please note, however, that good practice in writing code often does not apply to good practice in writing tests. This is one such example.